# Do I need to encode my $_GET URL?

Tags: php, html

When I first submit my search form via $_GET it returns results as expected but when using pagination and submitting it again for page X I see that it converts a portion of my URL and fails.

Here is the before and after URL portion that is changing:

```
// Before
min_score=1&max_score=10&not_scored=1

// After
min_score=1&max_score=10%AC_scored=1
```

It's encoding **10&** How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Well, what value do you want `max_score` to have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `&not` gets intepreted by the browser as `&not;`. Strict mode or any DOCTYPE might help.

And `&not;` simply gets substituted as `¬` then. Which in turn becomes `%AC` in request urls.

Besides [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/urlencode) on the individual values you should additionally apply [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) on the whole URL before you add it into the `<a>` tag.

Comment: That was it. I now call $query_string = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']); and it works great:) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

always type urls with

```
&amp;
```

instead of &...